# Unable to run Maven Commands on Docker as Non-root

Tags: java, maven, docker

I am building my project on docker (using docker-maven) and need to execute it as non-root.
From the official documentation, it seems that running maven as non-root is supported (https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven#running-as-non-root).

So I run the following:

`sudo docker run -v "$PWD":/var/maven -w /var/maven -ti -u 1000 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven maven mvn package -Duser.home=/var/maven`

where `$PWD` is my project root directory.

However, I always get permission related issue such as

`Error while storing the mojo status: /var/maven/mymodule/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission denied)`

or unable to delete some files if I run `mvn clean package` instead.

How do I run the command as non-root properly?